# Calculating the PPV and NPV using Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, bayes-theorem

A kit manufacturer markets a diagnostic kit for use in mass screening for
Thyroid disease. The diagnostic kit has the following specification:

Diseased Population: Has response variable of $N(11,64)$

Healthy Population:  Has response variable of $N(3,64)$

Where the response variable is the measured thyroid level in the patients’ sample.

$Q1$.) Show that the positive predictive value is $0.0437$ and the negative predictive value is $0.991$ if the prevalence of the disease is $2\%$

Applying Bayes' Theorem: $$\text{PPV} = \frac{0.02 \times \text{SE}}{0.02 \times \text{SE} + (1-0.02)(1-\text{SP})} $$

$$\text{NPV} = \frac{0.98 \times \text{SP}}{0.98 \times \text{SE} + (0.02)(1-\text{SE})} $$

I've tried doing simultaneous equations using MATLAB which gives $SE = 0.692651$ and $SP = 0.690663$ but I'm not sure how to calculate these values?

Comment: Where is the dividing line to decide the outcome of the screening test? Prevalence of what, relative to the two populations? Too much important context missing.to know what you're really asking, or how to answer.

Comment: Population 1 is dieseased population and Population 2 is healthy population where it is 2% prevalence of the disease. The distributions are the response variables for the level of disease in the samples.

Comment: There are currently two votes to close your question. Please edit this key information into the Question. Might help keep it 'alive' so you can get a helpful answer.

Comment: The test criterion uses a cutoff value of $c=7$: respective thyroid levels $X,Y$ of well/sick subjects under/over $7$ indicate health/disease. Sensitivity SE $=P(X<c)=P(Z<\tfrac{c-3}8)=\Phi(\tfrac{c-3}8)$ and specificity SP $=P(Y>c)=P(Z>\tfrac{c-11}8)=1-\Phi(\tfrac{c-11}8)$ for standard normal variates $Z$ and CDF $\Phi$. These both equal $\Phi(.5)=0.6915$ (`pnorm(.5)`, `pnorm(7,3,8)`, `1-pnorm(7,11,8)` in R) for $c=7$, which also minimizes the [diagnostic odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_odds_ratio#Interpretation) (DOR $=5.02$). This uses the $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues left unresolved, one minor and the others somewhat more difficult.

The minor difficulty is whether the second parameter of the normal
distributions is $\sigma^2 = 64$ or $\sigma = 64.$ Common sense
says it should be the former so that $\sigma = 8.$ Even so, there
is poor separation between the two normal curves of test scores.
So we cannot expect both high sensitivity and high specificity.

[image]

Another difficulty is to determine what cutoff thyroid score separates people deemed to test 'positive' for thyroid disease
(higher value) from those testing 'negative'. We need to choose
this score in a way so that prevalence is 2%.

The easy path is to find the 98th percentile of $Norm(3, 8).$
In essence, this means to equate values of sensitivity and prevalence. In R, we compute the cutoff score to be 19.43.

```
 qnorm(.98,3,8)
 ## 19.42999
```

But this neglects that out population is a $mixture$ of people
with and without thyroid disease. We can simulate
test scores of this mixed population of people who have the disease
and those who don't. Then see what cutoff score is consistent
with 2% prevalence of the disease. From this point of view,
the cutoff value should be 19.83. (Throwing away the part of
the population that were simulated with nonsensical negative
scores, the cutoff is 21.28.)

```
  B = 10^6;  bin = rbinom(B, 1, .02)
  pop = bin*rnorm(B,11,8) + (1-bin)*rnorm(B,3,8)
  quantile(pop, .98) 
  ##      98% 
  ##      19.83799
```

I  use the valus 19.8 to find sensitivity and specificity.
It is marked by the vertical line in the figure below.

[image]

Now, $SE = P(X > 19.8|\mu = 11) = .136.$

```
 SE = 1 - pnorm(19.8, 11, 8); SE
 ## 0.1356661
```

And $SP = P(0 < X < 19.8 | \mu = 3) = .628.$

```
 SP = diff(pnorm(c(0, 19.8), 3, 8)); SP
 ## 0.6283053
```

As noted above, both normal curves have substantial
probabilities below 0. Perhaps we should take the normal curves
as strictly positive and adjust the positive parts to enclose
unit probability for each curve. Then SE and (especially) SP become
larger:  $SE_{adj} = .148,\; SP_{adj} = .972.$

```
 SE.adj = SE/(1 - pnorm(0, 11, 8));  SE.adj
 ## 0.1481986
 SP.adj = SP/(1 - pnorm(0, 3, 8)); SP.adj
 ## 0.9723534
```

Finally, $PPV = P(\text{Has Disease}|\text{Positive Test}).$
According to your formula, this gives 0.0074 without adjustment
for negative areas, and 0.099 with adjustment. Both values are
quite low, but low PPV values are typical with low disease
prevalence.

```
 PPV = .02*SE/(.02*SE + .98*(1-SP)); PPV
 ## 0.007393768
 PPV.adj = .02*SE.adj/(.02*SE.adj + .98*(1-SP.adj)); PPV.adj
 ## 0.09860948
```

Summary: As you can see, the unresolved questions how to
find a cutoff score and how to deal with the fact that
both distributions stray far into negative territory have
led to many possible paths, some taken here and some not.

I do not claim any of this is $the$ answer to your question.
When you figure out how to resolve the difficulties, I hope
this will help you pick a useful path to the answer you need.

Comment: Please see my comment above, which I think clears up some confusion in the post and in your answer. I think the cutoff for the test has to be $c=7$ and the common standard deviation of healthy and sick thyroid levels is $\sigma=8$. Then, the populations are separated by one SD, the cutoff is at the midpoint, and sensitivity and specificity are balanced and equal to $\Phi(\tfrac12)=.6915=$`pnorm(.5)`. You can plot the dependence of these as well as PPV, NPV & DOR over a range of cutoff values $c$ for prevalence $p=.02$ to get a better picture: `c=seq(from=.1,to=13.9,by=.1); spc=pnorm(c,3,8)`...

Comment: @bgins. Glad to see you're making progress towards making sense of this. Still, it seems strange to use normal distributions to model test results that must extend far into negative values. Maybe OK to use normal if $\mu - 3\sigma$ is positive, but we're far from that here.